# Call Instantiate UIViewController from UITableViewController in Visual Studio using C# and Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

So using Visual Studio, C# and Xamarin and I have this
I have a UITableViewController which lists a selection of records and when the user clicks on one of these I want them to see a UIViewController page with the full record details displayed.

When a record is select this function is correctly invoked in RowSelected, the full code is below.

However I am seeing 2 errors:

```
PartsViewController PartsView= this.storyboard.InstantiateViewController("PartsViewController") as PartsViewController;
```

Shows this error for storyboard: [image]

```
this.PresentViewController(PartsView, true, null);
```

Shows this error for PresentViewController [image]

This is my first IOS App so can anyone show me the error of my ways please.

Code:

```
public partial class PartsListController : UITableViewController
{
    public List<String> Partss { get; set; }
    public List<String> Ndx { get; set; }
    static readonly NSString PartsListCellId = new NSString("PartsListCell");

    public PartsListController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(UITableViewCell), PartsListCellId);
        TableView.Source = new PartsDataSource(this);
        Partss = new List<string>();
        Ndx = new List<String>();
    }
     
    class PartsDataSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        PartsListController controller;

        public PartsDataSource(PartsListController controller)
        {
            this.controller = controller;
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            PartsViewController PartsView= this.storyboard.InstantiateViewController("PartsViewController") as PartsViewController;
            string selection = controller.Partss[indexPath.Row];
            string pos = controller.Ndx[indexPath.Row];
            this.PresentViewController(PartsView, true, null);
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return controller.Partss.Count;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(PartsListController.PartsListCellId);

            var row = indexPath.Row;
            cell.TextLabel.Text = controller.Partss[row];
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, you could have a try with [this sample](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uitableview-in-xamarin-ios-app/) to check whether it works in local site.

Comment: Hi Yes this example works it simply confirms that the rowselected function is being reached. What I am trying to do is open another view at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted
Here we go

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            PartsViewController PartsView= controller.storyboard.InstantiateViewController("PartsViewController") as PartsViewController;
            string selection = controller.Partss[indexPath.Row];
            string pos = controller.Ndx[indexPath.Row];
            controller.NavigationController.PushViewController(RecipeView, true);
        }
```